# What's the fastest way to compute the neighbours to a 2D, 3D, 4D, ND coordinate?

Tags: matlab

Assume that you have theese coordinates

```
2D: x, y
3D: x, y, z
4D: x, y, z, k
ND: x, y, z, k, ...
```

And the possible neighbours for e.g `2D` are

`x - 1, y`,

`x + 1, y`,

`x, y - 1`,

`x, y + 1`,

`x + 1, y + 1`,

`x - 1, y - 1`,

`x + 1, y - 1`,

`x - 1, y + 1`

You see, there are lots of combinations. Is there any easier way to compute these coordinates in the `Matlab` lanuage?

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you want is the displacements from a given (*x*, *y*, *z*, ...) point, that is, the −1, 0, 1 numbers in your example. Let *N* denote the number of dimensions.

You can compute the base-3 expresion of numbers 0, ..., 3<sup>*N*</sup>−1, with the middle number (3<sup>*N*</sup>−1)/2 (corresponding to all displacements equal to 0) removed. The results will be produced in lexicographical order:

```
N = 2;
result = dec2base([0:(3^N-1)/2-1 (3^N-1)/2+1:3^N-1], 3)-'1';
```

gives

```
result =
    -1    -1
    -1     0
    -1     1
     0    -1
     0     1
     1    -1
     1     0
     1     1
```

Comment: Could you not write `dec2base([0:3^N-1], 3) - 49` instead?`

Comment: @euraad Sure, but that would obscure the intention a little bit, i.e. that would work only because the codepoint of `'0'` is `48`. I have just changed it to `...-'1'`